# How do I make a small caption in the figure environment?

Tags: formatting

Here is a sample blueprint of the code

```
        \documentclass{beamer}

\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
        \begin{document}


    \begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}[H]
      \includegraphics[scale=0.38]{name of picture}
       \caption{caption text}
       \label{figure:1}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{remark}long remark\end{remark}
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

Basically the captions are too large (even the label "figure 1" is too large) and the spacing when I change the font size doesn't help unless I completely remove the caption for me to put the long remark in one slide without making two slides and one awkward slide.

I wish

1. Perhaps some way to make them both fit in.
2. A way to move the figure to the left and make a textbox for the remark.

Comment: Using a fully-captioned figure that is enumerated and `\label`ed and then later `\ref`erenced is somewhat awkward in a presentation. There's no way the audience will remember what Figure 2 looked like, really. In such cases, it's best to repeat the figure where needed to keep the audience engaged.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest not to use the `figure` environment in a presentation, since its purpose is to let the picture freely float, which is not what you want in a presentation; trying to fix it with `H` contradicts the reason for using `figure`.
Moreover, numbering figures and referring to them via `\label` doesn't make much sense in a presentation either, since the audience does not remember the images by number (in fact, figures do not even get numbered in `beamer`). Therefore I suggest to do it like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % Has anyone every used them?
\newcommand\mycaption[1]{{\footnotesize #1}}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.38]{example-image-a}\\
    \mycaption{Caption text}
  \end{center}
  \begin{remark}long remark\end{remark}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you want to introduce the caption with an emphasized 'Figure' to obtain the old look, just define `\mycaption` as:

```
\newcommand\mycaption[1]{{\footnotesize\structure{Figure:} #1}}
```

I wouldn't do it, since everyone sees that it is a figure, and there is also no reason to draw the attention of the audience to the word 'figure'.

[image]

**Edit:** Originally, I didn't notice the second question regarding positioning the image to the left. There are several ways how you can organize the material. You can put the image and caption into a `tabular`:

```
\begin{tabular}{c} \includegraphics ... \\ \mycaption ... \end{tabular}
```

and then position it side-by-side with a box containing further text. Or you can use `columns`, like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % Has anyone every used them?
\newcommand\mycaption[1]{{\footnotesize #1}}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[scale=0.38]{example-image-a}\\
      \mycaption{Caption text}
    \end{column}
    \hfill
    \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
      \begin{remark}
        Long remark long remark long remark.
        Long remark long remark long remark.
        Long remark long remark long remark.
        Long remark long remark long remark.
        Long remark long remark long remark.
        Long remark long remark long remark.
        Long remark long remark long remark.
      \end{remark}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways, I usually use the code below before the \begin{document}

```
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}
```

Using your example...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}
   \begin{document}
      \begin{frame}
        \begin{figure}[H]
          \includegraphics[scale=0.38]{name of picture}
          \caption{caption text}
          \label{figure:1}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{remark}long remark\end{remark}
      \end{frame}
   \end{document}
```

If you find \scriptize to small or too big you still have some options like: \tiny (smaller) and \footnotesize (bigger).

Another option is use a customize size:

```
\setbeamerfont{caption}{series=\normalfont,size=\fontsize{20}{24}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `captionsetup`

```
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize}} 
%scriptsize<footnotesize<small<normalsize<large
```

For more details check [here](http://www.lce.esalq.usp.br/clarice/Caption.pdf) (for font size: page 8)